# How to match user input with an existing string in an API array and print which array position was it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, include

I'm looking to compare a word that the user enters in an input with a list of words in an array that is present in an API that I'm trying to access. The thing is, for example, if the user types "Sun", I want to alert something like "Hey, you got it, Sun is present in [7]", where [7] would be the array position which has the string containg the word "Sun".

The array that the code is looking through is the `movie.title`, that actually is a list of movies that contains each movie's titles.

The problem is that I the code I'm posting here is only working with a hardcode string in the `includes()` present in `if (movie.title.includes("Pom"))`. I need it to accept the variable `userWord`, but when I use the variable nothing happens.

Furthermore, how am I able to point which array position contains the match?
I do not know if I was clear enough, I usually just read through Stackoverflow.

The code I'm posting here I basically got from a tutorial online. I tried to make this work in Vue (that is where I'm trying to make my app) but couldn't, so I used this piece of code. I do not know if it's the best way in terms of performance or writing.

Thank you.

```
requestAndcheckIf: function () {

        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
        request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);

        request.onload = function () {
            // Begin accessing JSON data here
            const data = JSON.parse(this.response);

            data.forEach(movie => {
                // Log each movie's title
                console.log(movie.title);

                if (movie.title.includes("Pom")) {
                    alert("Gotcha! It is present in the " + )
                } else {

                }
            });


        }

        request.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch **onchange** event of your input box. I hope you have an input with its ID or class.
with jQuery you can do this like

```
$("#buttonId").on("click", function(){

   userInput = $("#userWord").val();
   requestAndcheckIf(userInput);
})
```

and change your **requestAndcheckIf** with taking one parameter like

```
requestAndcheckIf: function (userInput) {

        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
        request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);

        request.onload = function () {
            // Begin accessing JSON data here
            const data = JSON.parse(this.response);

            data.forEach((movie, index) => {
                // Log each movie's title
                console.log(movie.title);

                if (movie.title.includes(userInput)) {
                    alert("Gotcha! It is present in the " + index)
                } else {

                }
            });
        }
        request.send();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have an ID for the input. Actually the user types the word and then hit a button, I forgot to add this "detail", really sorry, but for the bottom part I'm confident, I'll test it, thank you!

Comment: Updated my answer, Have a look.

Comment: I tested it with the "pom" hardcoded and it worked, thank you!

But for the `user input`:

I have this variable created `let userWord = document.querySelector(".header-input").value;
          
` that captures what the user typed. When I use this instead of the "Pom" nothing happens (the else void is what happens, actually), so the `if/else` statement only works if I type a string there, it does not accept the variable. Any idea?

Comment: Finally! I just got it right. I was having some problems with scope, classical. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

As for finding the index:

The syntax of `Array#forEach()` is as follows:

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    //your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

Meaning, the second parameter passed to the callback function is the current index, you can just use that here:

```js
requestAndcheckIf: function() {

  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
  request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);

  request.onload = function() {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    const data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    data.forEach((movie, index) => {
      // Log each movie's title
      console.log(movie.title);

      if (movie.title.includes("Pom")) {
        alert("Gotcha! It is present in the " + index)
      } else {

      }
    });


  }

  request.send();
}
```

But, if you just want to find the index of something, you can use `Array#findIndex()`:

```js
requestAndcheckIf: function() {

  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
  request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true);

  request.onload = function() {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    const data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    let index = data.findIndex(movie => movie.title.includes("Pom"));
    alert("Gotcha! It is present in the " + index)


  }

  request.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the right structure, it worked to find which position contained that word!

Comment: If I wanted to show the content of the index from `alert("Gotcha! It is present in the " + index)`, how could I do that? I mean, instead of showing the position, show the value that is contained in that position, for example in the array:

`title = ["Car", "Ball", "Book", "Sky"]`

I wanted to show the content of the `[2]`, that would be "Book", how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can also look at findIndex method available in Arrays.

```
var index = data.findIndex(function findFirstLargeNumber(movie) {
  return movie.title.includes("Pom") ;
})
```

here the index should give you the index you are looking

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex